# is there css to fade edges of a div?

Tags: css

I want to create a modal popup (for mobile) which will display a success message.

I am currently adding an opaque back overlay to the entire content, using

```
.overlay {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

but i was wondering if there is a way to only fade/ overlay the edges of the screen? like this but in reverse:

[image]

Comment: Read about CSS's `box-shadow`

Comment: "like this but in reverse" Can you show what you mean with a picture? I have no idea how to 'reverse' that image to produce what your describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing such faded style with CSS3. But it's better to apply a combination of both [Gradient Border](http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/) and [Inset Box Shadow](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/). You may get a much better idea on this [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/html5web/pen/lvrBn)